# Problems with install of Windowbuilder Java Oxygen, Mac, error message: "selected wizard could not be started" (empty windowbulder plugin/ folder)

Tags: java, macos, windowbuilder

I installed Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) again(a few times today). After installing the WindowBuilder plugin, I was surprised to see that I can't use it. The plugin installs successfully, but when I click on any of its components under Swing Designer, I get an error message that says that the 'selected wizard could not be started.'

I've not been able to find out exactly what's causing. After starting from scratch with Oxygen and Java 9, I can't seem to be able to use WindowBuilder anymore? I tried to install/deinstall WindowBuilder several times, deleted all projects...

There is no good solution for this problem to find on google. 
Maybe someone can help! :)))

See picture below...
[image]